# Excel Autoplot calendar

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I'm trying to setup make an excel sheet where a certain range would return as true on an IF statement if any of the cell has true value.

It should look like this

```
...A - B
R1 1 .. 3
R2 2
R3 3
R4 4
```

`=if((A1:A4)=B1, "YES", "NO")`

The formulated cell should appear as YES because the range A1:A4 has a cell that has 3 on it, however to no luck, I can't seem to formulate it properly.

Comment: It would only appear as "YES" if and only if A1 is 3.

Answer (score 0):

IF doesn't work on range input, you can use this formula instead:

`=IF(COUNTIF(A1:A4,B1)>0,"YES","NO")`

[image]